# Connecting aws backend to firebase database

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, firebase

I'm currently running python code in my aws server and trying to connect to my friend's firebase database. I read the documentation provided by firebase to connect to aws server.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

I have followed every step but I'm getting an error when I try to connect to my server. I have added google-service.json for credential.
Error that I get :

> ValueError: Invalid service account certificate. Certificate must
>   contain a "type" field set to "service_account".

Do I need to modify the **google-services.json** ?

My code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials


cred = credentials.Certificate('/home/ec2-user/google-services.json')
#default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
other_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, name='other')
ault_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

google-services.json is typically the name of an Android app configuration file.  That's not the same as a service account.  To get a hold of the credentials for a service account for your project, you'll need to generate one from the Firebase console from Project Settings -> Service Accounts.  The documentation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app).  Once you have this file, you can initialize the Admin SDK with it to begin accessing the data in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Better way would be to store credentials on s3 (encrypted) with a IAM role attached to lambda function.

```
import os
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
import boto3
from settings.local_settings import AWS_REGION, ENVIRONMENT
import json

firebase_config_file = 'app-admin-config-{}.json'.format(ENVIRONMENT)
firebase_admin_creds_file = 'app-admin-sdk-{}.json'.format(ENVIRONMENT)

current_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
files = [f for f in os.listdir(current_dir) if os.path.isfile(f)]

if firebase_config_file not in files and firebase_admin_creds_file not in files:
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=AWS_REGION)
    bucket = s3.Bucket('app-s3-secrets')

    firebase_config = json.loads(
        bucket.Object('app-admin-config-{}.json'.format(ENVIRONMENT)).get()['Body'].read())
    firebase_admin_creds = json.loads(
        bucket.Object('app-admin-sdk-{}.json'.format(ENVIRONMENT)).get()['Body'].read().decode())

class Firebase:
    @staticmethod
    def get_connection():
        cred = credentials.Certificate(firebase_admin_creds)
        return firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, firebase_config)


app = Firebase.get_connection()
```